# Sorted Hadoop WordCount Java

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am running the WordCount program of Hadoop in Java and my first job (getting all the words and their count) works fine.
However I come across a problem when I'm doing the second job who should sort it by their occurence number.
I've already read this issue ([Hadoop WordCount sorted by word occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298432/hadoop-wordcount-sorted-by-word-occurrences)) to understand how to made a second job but I don't have the same problem.

my code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;


public class simpleWordExample {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
    } 


    public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value:values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

        }

    } 


class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
            int number = 999;
            String word = "empty";

            if (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String str0 = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                word = str0.trim();
            }

            if (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String str1 = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                number = Integer.parseInt(str1.trim());
            }
            context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(number));
        }

    }

}

class Reduce1 extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (IntWritable value:values) {
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(value.get()));
        }
      }
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Job job1 = new Job();
    Job job2 = new Job();

   job1.setJobName("wordCount");

   job1.setJarByClass(simpleWordExample.class);

   job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
   job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

   job1.setMapperClass(Map.class);
   job1.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
   job1.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

   job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
   job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

   FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job1, new Path("file:///home/cloudera/data.txt"));
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path("file:///home/cloudera/output"));


   job2.setJobName("WordCount1");

   job2.setJarByClass(simpleWordExample.class);

   job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
   job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

   job2.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
   job2.setCombinerClass(Reduce1.class);
   job2.setReducerClass(Reduce1.class);

   job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
   job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

   FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job2, new Path("file:///home/cloudera/output/part-00000"));
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path("file:///home/cloudera/outputFinal"));


   job1.submit();
   if (job1.waitForCompletion(true)) {
       job2.submit();
       job2.waitForCompletion(true);
   }
}
```

}

and the error i get in the console :

```
15/05/02 09:56:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/05/02 09:56:37 WARN conf.Configuration: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/05/02 09:56:37 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/05/02 09:56:39 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/05/02 09:56:39 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
15/05/02 09:56:39 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/05/02 09:56:41 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15/05/02 09:56:41 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/05/02 09:56:45 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1998350370_0001
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1998350370_0001
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1998350370_0001_m_000000_0
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/cloudera/data.txt:0+1528889
15/05/02 09:56:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1998350370_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
15/05/02 09:56:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/02 09:56:57 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15/05/02 09:56:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15/05/02 09:56:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
15/05/02 09:56:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 2109573; bufvoid = 104857600
15/05/02 09:56:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 25406616(101626464); length = 807781/6553600
15/05/02 09:56:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > sort
15/05/02 09:56:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
15/05/02 09:56:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
15/05/02 09:56:59 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1998350370_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: simpleWordExample$Reduce.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: simpleWordExample$Reduce.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: simpleWordExample$Reduce.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
    ... 13 more
15/05/02 09:57:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1998350370_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
15/05/02 09:57:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 21
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=1529039
        FILE: Number of bytes written=174506
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=30292
        Map output records=201946
        Map output bytes=2109573
        Map output materialized bytes=0
        Input split bytes=93
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=122
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=165613568
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=1528889
```

Thanks you for your time and help !

Edit Global : new api used

Answer (score 1):

Never used hadoop myself but it looks like hadoop is trying to instantiate a "Map" instance using the deafult no-args constructor. It's throwing NoSuchMethodException because it can't find a no-args constructor.

Comment: yeah but the first Mapper I use doesn't have a constructor either and it works :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following lines from your code :

```
-- Map 1:
class Map1 extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> 

   -- From Driver
conf2.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
```

When you set the input format to TextInputFormat The Map Key is always LongWritable & value as Text. You have correctly used the TextInputFormat in **Map** class.

Comment: This seems very logical so I did it (as you can see on the edit), Map1 has now the same structure as Map but I still have the same console log :/

Comment: Another issue is output of the map1 and input of the reducer1 do not match. Map1 says text, intwritable while reduce1 takes intwritable & text in that order.

Comment: Done & post edit. No change in the log :/ Could the error be when I set everything in the main because it says "configuration error" ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the mix and match of the APIs. There are 2 APIs for hadoop the older being mapred and latest being mapreduce.
And in your code, you are importing both of them. Try commenting

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
```

and import all the files that you will require for your new API. Hope this works for you.

After commenting that, Try writing your code according to new API.

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
    }
}
} 


public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
        Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int sum = 0;
    for (IntWritable value:values) {
        sum += value.get();
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

}
}
```

I have written the first Mapper and reducer for you, you can do the same for second mapper and reducer.

Comment: In the reduce method I got an error in "IntWritable value:values" it says "Type mismatch : cannot convert from element type object to Intwritable"

Comment: I used the doc to put everything up to date even the main method but when I lunch the program, the first maping isn't done, you can see the new log on my post. I look here : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603788/hadoop-jobconf-class-is-deprecated-need-updated-example

Answer (score 0):

Classes **Map1**, **Reduce1** and **Reduce** have to be **static**.

There is also an error in job2 configuration:

job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

You should change it to:

job2.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

I hope this helps.